# pin/mark multiple locations on map in HTML5, javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to display multiple locations based on the latitude/longitude data available in a XLSheet. This functionality should be accomplished using HTML5, javascript or jquery. Can you help me how I can do this?

Comment: Use google map javascript api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?csw=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best tutorial link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

One more thing just make one array in initialize function and then just change marker position with the help of for loop from the array value. your problem will be solved in seconds for example:

```
 var Locations = [{
              lat:32.81553000000002, 
              lon:42.190242, 
              address:'sdf',
              gval:'1',
              aType:'Oil',
              title:'abc',
              descr:'abc'             
            },
                 {
              lat:-9.481553000000002, 
              lon:147.190242, 
              address:'Port Moresby',
              gval:'1',
              aType:'Oil',
              title:'Papua New Guinea',
              descr:'Papua New Guinea'            
            }
    ];
        for (i = 0; i < Locations.length; i++) {                            
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: Locations[i].title,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(Locations[i].lat, Locations[i].lon),           
            icon: img
        });



    }
```

Place this code in your initialize function. Gud luck

Comment: you need to define marker, map etc in extra, it is just for your problem code place with that all.

Comment: I am able to mark multiple points using the code above. is it possible to do the same functionlity using html5 geolocation API?

Comment: my code will work in html5,js,jquery.... accept ans if it will helpful ..... also learn attached tutorial also

Comment: I know it works in html5. My point is, can we achieve similar functionality using html5 geolocation API without using the google API

Comment: yes you can for its tutorial go to w3school html5 geolocation.... gud luck but it is necessary to use google map api in script tag